# How to use generic component in react native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

For example `export class FlatList<ItemT> extends React.Component<FlatListProps<ItemT>>` has `ItemT` generic type in it. How do I use it in `.tsx` code? Not parametrized looks like this:

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
```

But I would like my `renderItem` method to have a specific class:

```
renderItem = (item: ListRenderItemInfo<DataItem>) => {
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you return from the `renderItem` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript 2.9 has added support to explicitly specify the type parameter to a tsx tag. This is the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22415) for this. So applying the syntax, it should be:

```
<FlatList<DataItem>
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
    />
```