# TypeScript React Native Flatlist: How to give renderItem the correct type of it's item?

Tags: typescript, object, react-native, typescript-typings, react-native-flatlist

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript. `renderItem` complains that the destructured item implicitly has an `any` type. I googled and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743606/how-to-use-generic-component-in-react-native-with-typescript) and tried to implement what they teach here combined with the types in `index.d.ts` of the `@types` package for React Native.

```
export interface Props {
  emotions: Emotion[];
}

class EmotionsPicker extends PureComponent<Props> {
  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;
  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem title={item.name} checkmark={item.checked} />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList<Emotion>
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        data={this.props.emotions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. How can I give item the type `Emotion`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React FlatList with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079973/react-flatlist-with-typescript)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I know it's an old question but people googling it might still appreciate it.

```
import { FlatList, ListRenderItem } from 'react-native'
/*
.
.
.
*/
  renderItem: ListRenderItem<Emoticon> = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem title={item.name} checkmark={item.checked} />
  );
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. In particular I was trying to see where I was supposed to import it from

Answer (score 70):

I found a solution (though I don't know if it's ideal):

```
renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Emotion }) => (
  <ListItem title={item.name} checkmark={item.chosen} />
);
```

Answer (score 28):

This is because at the time `renderItem` is defined, TypeScript has no way of knowing it's supposed to go as the `renderItem` prop of `FlatList`.

If you had skipped the variable and directly plopped the function in the prop, TypeScript should be able to infer it correctly:

```
export interface Props {
  emotions: Emotion[];
}

class EmotionsPicker extends PureComponent<Props> {    
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList<Emotion>
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem title={item.name} checkmark={item.checked} />}
        data={this.props.emotions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this would work. But since i'm using a `PureComponent`, using a lambda-function like that would defeat the purpose. Therefore I need to pass it like this: `renderItem={this.renderItem}`.

Comment: @J.Hesters Then you have no choice but to define the types in the signature all over again, like you've done in your answer.

Comment: This is the real answer. It's the native implementation and will work regardless of the method needed: keyExtractor, renderItem, etc.

Answer (score 20):

I found a solution that worked pretty well for me:

```
import { FlatList, ListRenderItemInfo } from 'react-native';


<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }: ListRenderItemInfo<ItemType>) => (
    <ItemComponent item={item} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item: ItemType) => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

If not an inline function, the correct type exported from React for this when destructured is `ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT>`:

```
export interface ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT> {
    item: ItemT;

    index: number;

    separators: {
        highlight: () => void;
        unhighlight: () => void;
        updateProps: (select: "leading" | "trailing", newProps: any) => void;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I feel like the answers here only address how to in better cases fix and in worse cases bypass the type checking, but fail to explain why it does not work or why it should be typed the way it is.

I'd like to provide some more clarity as to why this fails for most people as it's very poorly documented even on the official [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) wiki.

---

#### Why you're getting error:

The component `FlatList` method does not expect a render function you are commonly used for passing (i.e.) standard react element constructor `(props) => JSX.Element`.

For better or for worse, `FlatList`'s `renderItem` method is typed the following way:

```
type ListRenderItem<ItemT> = (info: ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT>) =>
   React.ReactElement | null;
```

This is because it does not expect a direct element constructor as you would standardly construct `renderItem` methods as you are used to in most React patterns.

Instead it expects a **callback with a specific type**. This is for internal handling of optimalization purposes, but it still is rather clunky when it comes to typing.

```
export interface ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT> {
    item: ItemT;
    index: number;
    separators: {
        highlight: () => void;
        unhighlight: () => void;
        updateProps: (select: 'leading' | 'trailing', newProps: any) => void;
    };
}
```

---

#### Proper way to type the function

So it means we should treat our own internal `renderItem` as a callback as well with specific item prop where we pass the specific `<ItemT>` generic

```
type Props = {
  emotions: Emotion[]
}

// This is the standard React function component
const Item = (({ title, checked }): Emotion) => (
   <ListItem title={title} checked={checked} />
)

// This is the callback for constructing the function component
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<Emotion> = ({ item }: ListRenderItemInfo<Emotion>) => (
   <Item title={item.title} checked={item.checked} />
)
```

As you can see, this might be fairly confusing on first glance and easy to mix-up. In the `ListRenderItem<T>` tells typescript, we're looking to create a function of type `T` (generic argument) which then constructs *(returns)* a `Reat.ReactElement | null`. But since React Components themselves are functions, we still need to pass the function to create one. This is where the confusion and the type error stems from.

This essentially

1. Creates a callback of `ListRenderItem<T>`
2. Which accepts only specific propType of `ListRenderItemInfo<T>` with the prop `item`
3. Which then expects constructor function `(props: T) => JSX.Element`

instead of the the standard way of passing props and creating element from it. That's also why you're *(were)* getting the following [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) errors:

```
Property 'property name' does not exist on ListRenderItem<any>
```

Answer (score 2):

With TypeScript use this to avoid Type Error

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

In FlatList

```
  <FlatList
       data={list}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
       ....
       />
```

**The Type of index is Number and FlatList requires a string type value as its keys.**

Comment: Index shouldn't be used as key when the order of items may change.

Answer (score 1):

Founded amazing way to solve this problem

```js
import { ListRenderItemInfo } from 'react-native'

interface PlayerDataStructure {
  imageUrl: string;
  doubleValue: string | number;
  singleValue: string | number;
  isFavorite: boolean;
  name: string;
  thirdRowFirstLabel: string;
  thirdRowSecondLabel: string;
  thirdRowThirdLabel: string;
  thirdRowFourthLabel: string;
  id: number
}

const player: Array<PlayerDataStructure> = [
  { imageUrl: imageUrl, doubleValue: '43', singleValue: '01', isFavorite: true, name: 'Jerome Bell', thirdRowFirstLabel: '19 y', thirdRowSecondLabel: '183 cm', thirdRowThirdLabel: '75 kg', thirdRowFourthLabel: 'Right (2HB)', id: 0 },
  { imageUrl: imageUrl, doubleValue: '43', singleValue: '01', isFavorite: false, name: 'Jerome Bell', thirdRowFirstLabel: '19 y', thirdRowSecondLabel: '183 cm', thirdRowThirdLabel: '75 kg', thirdRowFourthLabel: 'Right (2HB)', id: 1 },
];

  // Render Item
  const renderPlayerData = (object: ListRenderItemInfo<PlayerDataStructure>) => {
    const { item } = object;
    return (
      <PlayerCard imageUrl={item.imageUrl} doubleValue={item.doubleValue} singleValue={item.singleValue} isFavorite={item.isFavorite} name={item.name} thirdRowFirstLabel={item.thirdRowFirstLabel} thirdRowSecondLabel={item.thirdRowSecondLabel} thirdRowThirdLabel={item.thirdRowThirdLabel} thirdRowFourthLabel={item.thirdRowFourthLabel} />
    )
  }

 <FlatList
          numColumns={2}
          data={player}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={renderPlayerData}
          contentContainerStyle={{ gap: PLAYER_CARD_VERTICAL_PADDING, paddingTop: 67 }}
          columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was importing `FlatList` from `react-native-gesture-handler` instead of `react-native`. The type inference didn't work properly in that scenario, but worked fine when I fixed the import.

The type of the item passed to `renderItem` *should be inferrable* from the type of the `data` array when properly done, and you shouldn't have to specify/override types.

Comment: Have the same issue. Strange oversight from react-native-gesture-handler

Answer (score 0):

const renderItem = ( {item}:{item:{ id:number, name:string , check:boolean }}) => { return ( ) }

Answer (score -1):

this solution works perfectly fine for me

```
interface Props {
    emotions: Emotion[];
}

class EmotionsPicker extends React.Component<Props> {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return (
            <FlatList<Emotion>
                data={this.props.emotions}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        );
    }

    renderItem: ListRenderItem<Emotion> = (props: ListRenderItemInfo<Emotion>): ReactElement<Emotion, string | JSXElementConstructor<Emotion>> => {};

    keyExtractor = (item: Emotion): string => {};
}
```