# React FlatList with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypeScript is really great, just for the moment I feel like I work for TypeScript more than TypeScript works for me.

I have a FlatList that renders restaurant results in a Carousel.

```
 const renderRestaurantRows = ({ item }) => (
    <Carousel
      id={item.id}
      name={item.name}
    />
  );
  const renderBottomSheetRestaurantList = () => (
    <View style={[styles.listView, { height: topSnapPoint }]}>
      <FlatList
        data={restaurants}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `row-${item.id}`}
        renderItem={renderRestaurantRows}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

TypeScript complains about `item` with `Binding element 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type` - makes sense. So I try to tell it what to expect:

```
  interface RestaurantItem {
    item: {
      id: string;
      name: string;
    };
  }
  const renderRestaurantRows = ({ item }: RestaurantItem) => (
    <Carousel
      id={item.id}
      name={item.name}
    />
  );
```

But then TS complains about `data={restaurants]` with `Type 'Restaurant[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly { id: string; name: string; imageUrl: string; rating: number; reviews: number; }` and a ton of other information.

Any chance someone can share a solution AND explain how to find such a solution in the future for other similar cases?

## UPDATE

`restaurants` is fetched from a custom hook. It is defined as an array of Restaurant objects:

```
interface Restaurant {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
export default function useRestaurantSearch() {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState<Restaurant[] | null>(null);
  ...
```

## UPDATE 2

Guys thanks for the comments, following the two suggestions, I rewrote the code:

```
import useRestaurantSearch from '../hooks/useRestaurantSearch';
export default function RestaurantPage() {
  const renderRestaurantRows = ({ item }: Restaurant) => (
    <Carousel
      id={item.id}
      name={item.name}
    />
  );
  const renderBottomSheetRestaurantList = () => (
    <View style={[styles.listView, { height: topSnapPoint }]}>
      <FlatList
        data={restaurants}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `row-${item.id}`}
        renderItem={renderRestaurantRows}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

This time I am getting an error for `{ item }: Restaurant` with `Cannot find name 'Restaurant'`. And it's not surprising because Restaurant is defined in an external hooks file `../hooks/useRestaurantSearch`. Do I need to import it somehow?

## UPDATE 3

After hours of playing around with this, I got to this point:

```
  const renderRestaurantRows = (result: { item: Restaurant }) => {
    return <Carousel {...result.item} />;
  };
  const renderBottomSheetRestaurantList = () => (
    <View style={[styles.listView, { height: topSnapPoint }]}>
      <FlatList
        data={restaurants}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `row-${item.id}`}
        renderItem={renderRestaurantRows}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

`renderItem` generates an object which contains each restaurant data under an `item` key. So for example, one of the objects could be:

```
{
  "index": 18,
  "item": Object {
    "coordinates": Object {
      "latitude": 123,
      "longitude": -123,
    },
    "id": "dfg987fshjsdfh",
    "name": "Yummy Food",
  },
  "separators": Object {
    "highlight": [Function highlight],
    "unhighlight": [Function unhighlight],
    "updateProps": [Function updateProps],
  },
}
```

When I pass a `result` object, I can let TS know about `item` inside the object and casting it to the Restaurant type. I do it with (result: { item: Restaurant })`. However, when I try to directly destructure the` result`object with`({ item }: Restaurant)`it gives me the error`Property 'item' does not exist on type 'Restaurant'`. Any idea why?

Comment: How did you define type of ```restaurants```? Try to annotate this array with RestaurantItem[]

Comment: @Drag13 Please see my updated question.

Comment: You are fetching type Restaurant but, want to process type RestaurantItem. They are not compatible, and TypeScript complains about that. You should either use the same type or subset of the Restaurant type

Comment: @Drag13 I updated my code and question following that last comment. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I would say that you find the solution, just import the type and you should be ok)

Comment: @Drag13 thanks! I think I pretty much got it, just one little question left.

Comment: @ben I believe if you're destructuring you would need to do: `{ item }: { item: Restaurant }`

Comment: @MattAft you are correct. Thank you. I thought that by destructuring, I'm casting the object itself to the TS type (if that makes sense). Lesson learned.

Comment: np and yeah I definitely ran into this as well haha

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701665/typescript-react-native-flatlist-how-to-give-renderitem-the-correct-type-of-it/66519421

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try importing ListRenderItem and type the const receiving the function:

```js
import { ListRenderItem } from 'react-native';
...
const renderRestaurantRows: ListRenderItem<Restaurant> = ({ item }) => (
  <Carousel
    id={item.id}
    name={item.name}
  />
);
```

What you're really getting as arguments from the renderItems is:

[image: ListRenderItem]

Where `ItemT` is your type, `Restaurant`.

Comment: I have a feeling this is really the better way to do this.

Comment: This solved my problem. The only thing is you need to make sure renderRestaurantRows returns the JSX or Typescript will still give you an error.

Comment: am I the only one, or this no longer works in sep 2023

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the item to render is a `Movie`:

```
    _renderItem(info: ListRenderItemInfo<Movie>): ReactElement<Movie> {
        return <MovieTile movie={info.item} />;
    }

    render() {
        let movies = this.props.movies;

        return <FlatList
            data={movies}
            horizontal={true}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.id.toString()}
            />;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. How could you convert that code into functional component "style" ? Thanks

Comment: You can define inner function to `renderItem`.

Comment: Remember to `import { ListRenderItemInfo } from 'react-native';`