# How to typing renderItem Flatlist received by prop in react native and TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, interface, react-native-flatlist

I have a component `HorizontalList` that render this:

```
<HorizontalList
  data={categories}
  renderItem={renderCategories}
  titleList={'Categories'}
/>
```

[image]

this is my component file that receives the following props

```
//HorizontalList.tsx

interface Props {
  titleList: string;
  data: object[];
  renderItem: <--- //IDK what type should be here;
}

const HorizontalList: React.FC<Props> = ({titleList, data, renderItem}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>{titleList}</Text>
      <FlatList horizontal data={data} renderItem={renderItem} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

but I dont know what type should be `renderItem` prop, I tried with `() => JSX.Element` , but in  I get the error:

```
Type '({ item }: { item: ICategorieItem; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '() => Element'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so;

```
  interface Props {
    titleList: string;
    data: ICategorieItem[];
    renderItem: ({
      item: ICategorieItem,
      index: number,
    }) => React.ReactElement;
  }
```

or alternatively, you can make use of `ListRenderItem` from `react-native`.

For more alternatives, please see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701665/typescript-react-native-flatlist-how-to-give-renderitem-the-correct-type-of-it).

```
    // data prop type definition for FlatList

    data: ReadonlyArray<ItemT> | null | undefined;

    // renderItem prop type definition
    renderItem: ListRenderItem<ItemT> | null | undefined;
```

When you also see the type defs for `renderItem` and `data` props, you will notice that props of those receiving exact same generic type.

Comment: Thanks for read.. I tried with your recomendation and with ListRenderItem too, but it doesnt worked :( , the error is similar: `Type '({ item }: { item: ICategorieItem; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem<object>'.`

Comment: Yes data type should be ICategorieItem[] instead of object[]...